# openni_tracker failed because of InitFromXml failed

Tags: openi-tracker, ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,I am a new user of ROS openni.
Now I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and my ROS dist is groovy.
when I run the command rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker,the only thing I got is a error message:
InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!

I followed several solutions on the ROS community,still get the same error message

I googled a lot ,but not a correct solution for me.Any help will be appreciated ,It really drives me crazy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53504/openni_tracker-failed-because-of-initfromxml-failed/) by [WIZARD1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2798/wizard1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WIZARD1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2798/wizard1/) on 2013-01-27**:
just like this link http://answers.ros.org/question/9737/openni_tracker-initfromxml-failed-cant-create-any-node-of-the-requested-type/.But It won't help

**Comment by [WIZARD1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2798/wizard1/) on 2013-03-02**:
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should install install `NITE-Bin-Dev`, as for me , I install `NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.21`
Then run the `install.sh` in it.
Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2015-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Inder](https://answers.ros.org/users/25019/inder/) on 2015-11-13**:
I have this same error with 14.04 on ROS Indigo. I have downloaded NITE-Bin-Dev-linux-x86-v1.5.2.23 and run the install.sh. Is there anything else that I can try?

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-11-13**:
You can read [this](https://github.com/futureneer/openni2-tracker) or [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/195459/skeletal-tracker-for-asus-xtion-pro-live/#209413)
Hope it helps.